# Inject PHP Variable(s) into XML Email Template

Tags: php, xml, templates

How can I inject PHP variables into my XML email templates?

My templates are structured like this:

```
<Template id="1" name="Registration">
    <![CDATA[
        <p>Dear $FullName,</p>
        <p>We would like to welcome you to oursite.  Please find your activation link below, <br />
        if you cannot click the link, please copy and paste the link into your browser.</p>
        <ul>
            <li><strong>Activation Link:</strong> <a href="http://example.com/activate/$actCode/$UserName">http://example.com/activate/$actCode/$UserName</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Thank you,<br />
        ~Kevin - our site</p>
    ]]>
</Template>
```

and the code I am pulling it in with is:

```
public function PullEmailTemplate($which, $id){
    $file = $which . '.config';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/assets/templates/' . $file, NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    $res = $xml->xpath("//Template[@id='" . $id . "']");
    return (string)$res[0]; 
}
```

and using it like:

```
$msg = PullEmailTemplate('user', 1);
```

Now, the email sends out successfully, but I get `$FullName`, `$ActCode`, and `$UserName` exactly as they are... in otherwords, the aren't outputting what they should be...  for instance they should be (in order): `Kevin`, `12345`, `myuser@name.com`

How can I do this?

Comment: now there's nothing.  Simply `$FullName`, `$ActCode`, and `$UserName` are now blank.  Yes I am 100% positive those variables are set with values.

Comment: Is there a way I can force the `(string)$res[0]` to be a template?  PHP is a templating language after all...

Comment: I thought that something like this may work... but it only causes the site to break... http://jungels.net/articles/php-templates.html

Comment: Once the message is in the msg variable, do some replacing with str_replace for the variables. That should work, but will only work for that specific document

Comment: This is an xml document, with a great many `<Template` nodes in it.  `str_replace`, and the answer below are unfeasible.

Comment: So the $msg variable gets ALL the templates at once? Why bother calling it with parameters?

Comment: no.  it doesnt get all templates at once

Comment: SO what is wrong with replacing the variables after you fetch the xml?

Comment: defeats the purpose dontcha think?   having to write an extra hundred or so replace statements...

Comment: Well if you want to replace text in a non-php file with php you don't have much of a choice other than to go replace it.

Comment: thus nullifying php as a templating language?

Comment: Technically, its just a server-side scripting language. You can use templates with it, but you have to create templates with PHP. There are Templating engines like Smarty to give you cleaner code than just a regular PHP page. But it wont be able to replace variables in external pages made from another language without replacing the variables.

Comment: Ok, then how can one simply do this? `echo "Hi $name";` and it outputs  `Hi Kevin`?   My point is, a string is a string is a string.  So why when I am attempting to basically do this same this, it won't/can't work?

Comment: Where do you set the $name variable and where do you call it? If you do $name = "Kevin"; echo $name; exit; it will work. If its empty, then the variable is not set.

Comment: I set `$name = 'Kevin';` then I load in the text from the XML file, and try to echo it.  `$name` is never replaced.

Comment: changed my function to include `$replacements` and added: `$ret = strtr($ret, $replacements);` and passing in an array of tokens/replacements   What I don't understand is why it isnt working like it should be period...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got a matryoshka here. The outer layer is an XML document. You already have source that reads the inner element from it. The inner element (inside the CDATA) is an HTML snippet with `$name` placeholders. You now need some source that replaces that placeholders without destroying the HTML.

If `$name` is the extend of that template system, you could use `preg_replace_callback()` to match them. The pattern `(\$[\w\d]+)` should do.

Comment: This is an xml document, with a great many `<Template` nodes in it.  `str_replace` and `preg_replace_callback()` are unfeasible

Comment: The XML is not the template, but the container for it. The HTML snippet inside the CDATA is the template with placeholders. A CDATA is a special kind of text nodes. Read the text and modify it.

Comment: Why not just run the HTML (in the CDATA) through some template parser/View layer? Set the variables and render.

Comment: The preg_replace_callback() in this case would be a (very basic) template system.